# Do I still need an explicit middle entity for N-to-N in EF under .NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I've read a few articles like [this one](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration#note) where it's implied that the necessity of an explicit entity AB between A and B.

When I google this, I can't find any official info confirming nor contradicting that statement. On the other hand, documentation for preview versions might be less than fully covering.

Is it possible in .NET Core 3 or are we still forced to manually create the N-to-N entities?

Comment: In reality n:m associations with a hidden join entity are hardly ever useful, because a join table only having two FKs tends to be utterly meaningless. I've *never* come across any useful case in enterprise applications. So to me it's OK for the EF team to give this low priority.

Comment: @GertArnold Interesting experience. For me, it's exactly the opposite. Student-teacher, member-tag, user-role, all those and many more are many-to-many and, as far I've experienced it, those are always a part of the basic fabric of the model. So it was interesting that your experience is diagonally opposite.

Comment: Konrad, I'd love to discuss this with you, but I don't think this is the right place. Let me conclude this by saying that a technical argument against hidden junction entities is that they require n:m associations to be manipulated by *independent associations* instead of more efficient *foreign key associations*. If the EF team could come with some smart solution for that I might get tempted...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The feature you (and not only) are asking for is tracked by [#10508: Implement many-to-many relationships without mapping join table](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508).

As you can see, the status is `Backlog`, which means it is considered, but no concrete schedule. Also the [last comment](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10508#issuecomment-389922109) by the EF Core team (manager) is

> Current plan for 3.0 is to implement skip-level navigation properties as a stretch goal. If property bags ([#9914](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9914)) also make it into 3.0, enabling a seamless experience for many-to-many could become easier.

Also it's not listed in the [New features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/features). And just referenced in [Property bag entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/features#property-bag-entities)

> This feature is a stepping stone to support many-to-many relationships without a join entity (issue [#1368](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368)), which is one of the most requested improvements for EF Core.

where #1368 refers to [Discussion on many-to-Many relationships (without CLR class for join table)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368).

---

All that simply means that the answer to your question is - no, this feature won't be in 3.0, hence you should continue using explicit join entity.

Comment: Awesome answer and +1 for linkage. The only thing I still can't wrap my head around is why oh why in the face of God was the feature removed in Core when it's apparently implemented and appreciated in the previous version of EF. I'm sure there's a very good reason for it but it seems to be a heck of a reason if it's still not fixed up into the third version... What's your take on it (if any)?

Comment: It's not removed. EF Core is redesign/reimplementation for the EF, so it's simply not implemented yet (I guess due to the typical reasons, you know - time, resources and priorities). The situation is quite similar with .Net Core vs Full .NET Framework.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. While understanding that it's a redesign and certain parts won't be available straight off, I'm surprised that a feature like this isn't numero uno on the prio list and gets implemented immediately or at least rather early. Core came out 2016 and we're in the 3rd iteration. Feels like it should have been done already but that there's a specific technical reason for the difficulty. I'm not in any way criticizing the team building it - I'm only curious if there's a complexity that I'm too ignorant to realize.

Comment: I understand your point. And also can't understand many of their priorities (although I post a lot in that area, I have no any relation with EF Core team). But in my practice I've been in a similar situation, and I guess the main criteria is that while highly requested, it's not a showstopper because of the existing alternative way to achieve the same thing. Definitely there are technical challenges, and also both approaches have pros and cons. The main challenge I guess is that it requires introducing a *non CLR* entity types, i.e. entities w/o associated class...

Comment: … And their design from the beginning relies on CLR classes. That's why they say implementing property bag entities concept will help them later implement the feature in question. But the main efforts for 3.0 are on the query translation which is the main problem and showstopper with EF Core from the beginning. Btw, since EF6 is going to support .Net Core (or .Net Standard), you'd really have a choice to use EF or EF Core depending on which one better fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to implement the middle entity! You can check this with the command:

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=DATABASE_IP;Initial Catalog=NAMEDATABASE;Integrated Security=True"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f -c DemoDbContext